# Delete duplicate string with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have got text file:

```
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 4 5 6 7
```

Here first and last line are simmilar. I have a lot of files that have double lines. I need to delete all dublicate.

Answer (score 13):

All these seem really complicated. It is as simple as:

```
gc $filename | sort | get-unique > $output
```

Using actual file names instead of variables:

```
gc test.txt| sort | get-unique > unique.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

To get unique lines:

```
PS > Get-Content test.txt | Select-Object -Unique
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

To remove the duplicate

```
PS >  Get-Content test.txt | group -noelement | `
      where {$_.count -eq 1} | select -expand name

1 3 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Caveat (just in case if ...): `Select-Object -Unique` is case sensitive and this is not configurable.

Comment: Good point and so is Get-Unique. I'm able to work around it with sort-object: 'one two three','one two Three','one Two three','one Two four' | sort -unique

Answer (score 2):

If order is not important:

```
Get-Content test.txt | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content test-1.txt
```

If order is important:

```
$set = @{}
Get-Content test.txt | %{
    if (!$set.Contains($_)) {
        $set.Add($_, $null)
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content test-2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = "C:\temp\filename.txt"
(gc $file | Group-Object | %{$_.group | select -First 1}) | Set-Content $file
```

The source file now contains only unique lines

The already posted options did not work for me for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$a = @{} # declare an arraylist type
gc .\mytextfile.txt | % { if (!$a.Contains($_)) { $a.add($_)}} | out-null

$a #now contains no duplicate lines
```

To set the content of $a to mytextfile.txt:

```
$a | out-file .\mytextfile.txt
```